# Moving QGraphicsPixmapItem and getting itemChange events

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` that I move around `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable)`, I activated the `ItemSendsScenePositionChanges` flag on my item but the function `itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)` isn't called when I move my item around.

Any sugestions?

Here is my code for itemchange():

```
#include "graphicspixmapitem.h"

GraphicsPixmapItem::GraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *parent, QGraphicsScene *scene)
  : QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent)
{

}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  //m_clicked_signal(this);
  //  emit clicked();
}
void GraphicsPixmapItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
  //m_clicked_signal(this);
    emit clicked();
}

#include <QDebug>
QVariant GraphicsPixmapItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == ItemPositionChange) {
            qDebug() << "Position changed";
        }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

and this is my code for setFlags:

```
QPixmap Trackinfo(":/images/ScreenContacts.png");
    buf = addPixmap(Trackinfo);
    buf->setPos(0, 40);
    buf->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    buf->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
    buf->setCacheMode(QGraphicsItem::ItemCoordinateCache);
```

Comment: Post your code where set the flag and your `itemChange(..)` method.

Comment: I have edited my post to show the asked code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the default implementation of QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent and QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent on your item's mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent?

If you don't call them, I suspect that you won't even be able to move the item with the mouse, since you aren't letting Qt know when the item was clicked/released.